# Error trying to use SQLDatabaseChain with Aurora MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, openai-api, langchain

I'm trying to tinker with Langchain following this example (https://coinsbench.com/chat-with-your-databases-using-langchain-bb7d31ed2e76). Instead of using PostgreSQL I'm trying to connect to a MySQL database. Everything looks accurate however I am getting an attribute error when trying to run the python script. This is the code:

```
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from langchain.utilities import SQLDatabase
from langchain_experimental.sql import SQLDatabaseChain

# Accessing the OpenAI Key
import environ
env = environ.Env()
environ.Env.read_env()

API_KEY = env('OPENAI_API_KEY')
HOST = env('HOST')
DBUSER = env('DBUSER')
PASSWPORD = env('DBPASS')
DATABASE = env('DATABASE')

# Create the database connection
mysql_uri = f"mysql+pymysql://{DBUSER}:{PASSWPORD}@{HOST}:3306/{DATABASE}"
db = SQLDatabase.from_uri(mysql_uri)

# Setup llm
llm = OpenAI(temperature=0, openai_api_key=API_KEY)

# Create db chain
QUERY = """
Given an input question, first create a syntactically correct mysql query to run, then look at the results of the query and return the answer.
Use the following format:

Question: Question here
SQLQuery: SQL Query to run
SQLResult: Result of the SQLQuery
Answer: Final answer here

{question}
"""

# Setup the database chain
db_chain = SQLDatabaseChain(llm=llm, database=db, verbose=True)

def get_prompt():
    print("Type 'exit' to quit")

    while True:
        prompt = input("Enter a prompt: ")

        if prompt.lower() == 'exit':
            print('Exiting...')
            break
        else:
            try:
                question = QUERY.format(question=prompt)
                print(db_chain.run(question))
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)

get_prompt()
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/StarScr3am77/Documents/Workspace/Hustle/tracking-bot/app.py", line 18, in <module>
    db = SQLDatabase.from_uri(mysql_uri)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/StarScr3am77/Documents/tracking-bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain_community/utilities/sql_database.py", line 124, in from_uri
    return cls(create_engine(database_uri, **_engine_args), **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/StarScr3am77/Documents/tracking-bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain_community/utilities/sql_database.py", line 65, in __init__
    self._inspector.get_table_names(schema=schema)
  File "/Users/StarScr3am77/Documents/tracking-bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/reflection.py", line 396, in get_table_names
    return self.dialect.get_table_names(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<string>", line 2, in get_table_names
  File "/Users/StarScr3am77/Documents/tracking-bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/reflection.py", line 97, in cache
    ret = fn(self, con, *args, **kw)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/StarScr3am77/Documents/tracking-bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/base.py", line 2924, in get_table_names
    % self.identifier_preparer.quote_identifier(current_schema)
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/StarScr3am77/Documents/tracking-bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 7356, in quote_identifier
    + self._escape_identifier(value)
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/StarScr3am77/Documents/tracking-bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 7315, in _escape_identifier
    value = value.replace(self.escape_quote, self.escape_to_quote)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!